# Algolia InstantSearch.js' searchFunction parameter not working

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js, instantsearch

Algolia's [InstantSearch.js](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/what-is-instantsearch/js/) is working really great. However, its `searchFunction` parameter doesn't seem to be working according to [their docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/instantsearch/js/#widget-param-searchfunction). Here's my `search` object:

```
const search = instantsearch({
    indexName: 'decks',
    searchClient,
    routing: true,
    searchParameters: { hitsPerPage: 10 },
    searchFunction(helper) {
        console.log('hi')
    }
})
```

Nothing ever gets written to the console and search functionality remains the same. So, it seems `searchFunction` is never called. I'm using InstantSearch.js v3.0.0, has `searchFunction` maybe been renamed to something else?

Comment: Did you managed to fix your issue?

Comment: @SamuelVaillant it seems to be working now, just checked 2 minutes ago. Not sure what happened. I had previously reset my browser to avoid caching issues, did a view source to make sure the right code was appearing. So I don't know why it's working now...

Comment: I've tested on my side the provided code and it did work. Anyway glad to see that you've solved your issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`searchFunction` does in fact work as an argument to `instantsearch`. Even though I had previously reset my browser to avoid caching issues and did a *view source* to make sure updated JavaScript code was being loaded, I apparently had an older version of the code running.

Hopefully this helps someone else. Though I suppose this is now a Chrome caching issue rather than an InstantSearch.js issue.